# merging multiple file with different extensions in single file

Tags: c, windows

I want make a function in order to pack multiples files into a single one using `C` language, and reverse the operation with another function.

```
int cbd_merge_files(const char** filenames, int n, const char* final_filename) {

  FILE* fp = fopen(final_filename, "wb");

  if (fp == NULL) return 1;

  char buffer[4097];

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {

    const char* fname = filenames[i];

    FILE* fp_read = fopen(fname, "rb");

    if (fp_read == NULL) return 1;

    int n;

    while ((n = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 4096, fp_read))) {

        int k = fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), n, fp);

        if (!k) return 1;
    }
    fclose(fp_read);

 }

 fclose(fp);

 return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
  cbd_merge_files(argv+1, argc-1, "output.txt");
  return 0;
}
```

I am using this code in order to make it work, but work only with TXT files, and not with different files like: exe, jpg, zip, rar etc ...

Is there a fix or another function to do the same job ? another approch/method ?

**Note:** I am using `Visual Studio 2010`

Thank's.

Comment: Describe how it does not work on non text file with more details.  How did you review the resulting `"output.txt"` in those cases - perhaps that viewer is the issue.  I suspect the unpack function is your culprit - which is not shown and makes this post unclear.

Comment: When i combine multiple different extentions files, iget error since all the files combined in the same one without delimiter or separator ... and have no idea on how to register too the name of files and unpack them back.

Comment: Then write the name length, name and file length into the merged file also.  Perhaps as simple as [64-length] [filename] [64-bit length file size] [file data].

Comment: Minor: `if (!k) return 1;` should be `if (k < n) { fclose (fp); fclose(fp_read); return 1; }`

Comment: Did you write the posted code?

Comment: @chux no i didn't, please can you show me how to do that: [64-length] [filename] [64-bit length file size] [file data] ?

Comment: Yes I can, but it would be better for you to post first what you have tried - even if it has a few flaws - else this post is too broad - too many good answers.  The code above all ready shows how to do some of the goal.

Comment: My goal is to merge many files with different extension and is there where i am blocked. I can't do more on what i have posted ... if anyone have an approche thank's to suggest.